# I have to find the difference of two consecutive timestamp .But I am getting 'NULL' in "diff" column in the resultset

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT t1.id AS id1, 
   t2.id AS id2, 
   t1.timestamp AS timestamp1, 
   t2.timestamp AS timestamp2, 
    Timestampdiff(second,t1.timestamp,t2.timestamp)
                            AS diff  
FROM logs12 AS t1
JOIN logs12 AS t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id - 1)
```

Data:
id timestamp
1  1484407056
2  1484407536
3  1484409756
4  1484410536
5  1484583336

Expected result
 id   diff
 2   8 min
 3   37 min
 4   13 min
 5   2 days

Comment: Can you please add some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id AS id1, 
  t2.id AS id2, 
  t1.timestamp AS timestamp1, 
  t2.timestamp AS timestamp2, 
  Timestampdiff(SECOND,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp) , 
  FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp))
                        AS diff  
 FROM logs12 AS t1
 JOIN logs12 AS t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id - 1)
```